# How can I create a "selected effect" using CSS for ul/lis?

Tags: html, css

[This](http://cssdesk.com/bwTwX) is what I have created so far. I want to increase the height of the first `li` item, so that it covers the bottom border of its `ul`.

In my app I want to create the "selected" effect using this approach. Is this possible without JS?

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    border: 5px solid #999;
    font-size: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the "selected" effect?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I want to use ul/li to implement a menu. When an li is selected, I want to push it down so that it is known to the user that it is currently selected. Like jQuery UI Tabs.

Comment: I believe you will need to use JavaScript to achieve this, and it would be achievable with little difficulty or code, especially with a js library like jquery.

Comment: i have updated the post below.check the working code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
li:first-child{
  margin-bottom:-5px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  }
```

Check this http://cssdesk.com/QWbvc

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just two questions: Why without setting `padding-bottom` it doesn't work? Also why `margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: -5px` works, but `margin-bottom: -5px` doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: padding is space between border and content.by default its 25px.'padding-bottom:30 px' will make it to cover bottom border of your ul.

Comment: Your normal LI's have padding-bottom:25px;. So, in the first LI i have addedd 5px padding which is 30px & at the same time i put margin-bottom:-5px which create a gap for border to take space.

Comment: @sandeep do you also know the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207095/why-a-negative-margin-bottom-on-an-element-decreases-the-height-of-parent-of-th ?

Answer (score 0):

you may refer sandeep's answer but also Try this one  - just assign fix height to parent element and the see how it works after `<li>` height increases

ul, li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

```
ul {
    border: 5px solid #999;
    font-size: 0;
    height:79px;
}

li{
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
}

li:first-child {
    height:25px;
}
```

OR

```
li:first-child {
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class like 'active' to your selected element, and then write some rules for your element. Check this jsfiddle.net/p85Ey/